# Dual citizenship at Maputo airport. No exit stamp

Tags: dual-nationality, passport-stamps, mozambique

I hold dual citizenship, Ghana and Mauritius. I currently reside in Ghana (departure country), and I am planning to travel to 3 countries in Southern Africa, Mozambique being the first port of entry. Although I will be departing from Ghana with my Ghanaian passport, I am planning to enter Mozambique (and the rest of the countries) using my Mauritian passport as it enjoys visa-free access to all 3 countries.

Given that the Mauritian passport will not have an exit stamp from Ghana, will immigration in Mozambique ask me why it doesn't have it? Will there be a complication entering on the Mauritian passport if I exited with the Ghanaian passport?

Comment: In my experience, immigration inspectors have never looked for exit stamps in my passport.  I've read about this happening at some land border crossings, however, and the only land borders I've crossed have been in North America and Europe.  I have never been to Mozambique, so I cannot comment on the practice there.

Comment: @phoog When getting off a ferry in North Cyprus, before reaching the proper passport control, two officers checked passports (all Turkish) for Turkish exit stamps outside the Ferry (in my case, using my ID, they requested the entry-exit form). One family had got very weak stamps and so were held there - I got the impression that they might even have been sent back.

Comment: @CGCampbell I've read on this site about border crossings in South America where this happened.  I can't find it now; perhaps it was in some comments somewhere.  A fictionalized account of this also appeared in the movie [Gabriel and the Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_and_the_Mountain).

Comment: I have two passports, and rotate through them. I have been asked a few times about exit stamps in Asia. Not very frequent, not not entirely uncommon.

Comment: @JonathanReez how is this a duplicate? That is a general question with general answers, while this is a specific question about the practices of Mozambiquan border officials at the Maputo airport.

Comment: @phoog a Nigerian-Mexican national traveling between Hong Kong and Tonga is exactly the same as a Filipino-Nicaraguan national traveling between Canada and Iceland. There's nothing to add here.

Comment: @dda What do you usually tell them? Do you just show the other passport with the exit stamp and it's all good? Or have they forced you to switch to the other passport (the one with the exit stamp)?

Comment: I just show the other passport. They check. Ok ok, they say. And hand it back. In Malaysia, they sometimes make noises about always using the same passport. I usually don't even bother answering.

Comment: @JonathanReez "nothing to add here": sure there is.  The question is whether immigration officials in Maputo airport will consider that the absence of a departure stamp in the passport of a Mauritian passport holder arriving from Ghana is a reason for additional scrutiny.  I don't know the answer to that question; do you?

Comment: @phoog the answer is the same for every country in the world: pull out your second passport and show them the stamps. Unless of course there's an issue with dual citizenship not being recognized, which is also explained in the canonical post.

Comment: @JonathanReez The answer to the question "is it a red flag" is a yes or no question; the answer you propose, "show the other passport," is not an answer to a yes or no question, is it?

Comment: @phoog it doesn't matter if it's a yes or no in the first place. If it's a yes, simply show the other passport. If not, go on your merry way. Same answer for any country from Argentina to Zimbabwe.